# Session Storage with AngularJS and ng-storage

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am developing a chat application.
I have the next HTML:

`<input type='text' id='nameInput' placeholder='Your Name'>`

I'm also working with AngularJS, this is my module:

```
var app = angular.module('principal', ['ngStorage']);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $sessionStorage) {
  $scope.$storage = $sessionStorage.$default(#nameInput);
});
```

As you can see, I have *ngStorage* as a dependency.
I am trying to sessionStorage the input value, so if the user accidentaly refresh the page, his name stills written in the input, but my code doesn't work, what can I do?

**UPDATE**
By now, thanks to Matt, I solved my doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind your view, in this case your input element, to a value in your model. You do this using `ng-model`. For example:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="state.nameInput" placeholder="Your Name">
```

Then you just need to set your scope in your controller.

```
$scope.state = {
    nameInput: 'John'
};
```

---

If you want to instead want to use ngStorage as the binding (instead of a regular $scope value), try the following in your controller:

```
$scope.$storage = $sessionStorage.$default(/* any defaults here */);
```

And in your html

```
<input type="text" ng-model="$storage.nameInput" placeholder="Your Name">
```

---

Basically, what you are saying is; Put the `$sessionStorage` object directly on the `$scope`, so that the view can reference it, and its children. Then you tell the `<input>` that you want its value to reference a particular child on that scope using `ng-model`. So when you change a value on the input, it will change the scope model value, which in turn will update the session storage.

Comment: Ok, I understand. But I think something is missing. Here is my doubt in a more explained way:
1. A user enters to my page and sees the input.
2. He writes his name.
3. Accidentally he refreshes the page.
4. Even if so, his name still written on the input.
Is this a good explanation of my doubt?

Comment: As in are you worried that your example will happen, or won't happen? Because if you bind to session storage is should persist. If you want to remove it, you will need to clear it manually at some point.

Comment: I wan't it to happen.

Comment: This is [my page](https://pablo-ivan.github.io), it's written in Spanish, but the thing that I want to show you is that when you write your name on the top or bottom input, the model actualize as it would, but if you refresh the page, you have to enter your name again

Comment: What I want is that even when you refresh the page, your name still in there.

Comment: Can you update your site (or create a demo elsewhere) with an attempt at using $sessionStorage (like my answer above)?

Comment: Your example doesn't implement the solution the way my answer explains. It appears you misunderstand how angulars binding works, so i suggest reading more examples, and doing more experiments. I have updated your code example (which works) [here](http://jsbin.com/hukogagepe/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Ok, it works. My page now has a sessionStorage fully working. Thanks Matt for clarifying my doubt.

Comment: Well, I've made some big updates, now it fully works [here](https://pablo-ivan.github.io/en).